# Dynamically adding modal information based on button clicked

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, bootstrap-modal

I'm using AngularUI Modal and AngularUI Router with Bootstrap. I would like to populate the modal title and add an item to the submitted array based on which button a user clicks to initiate the modal. I can statically add this information, but am having trouble figuring out how to add this information dynamically.

[EDIT: Added code for modal below]

Javascript for Controller:

```
myApp.controller('NewProjectCtrl', function ($scope, $location,  $stateParams, Projects, $modalInstance) {
 var editProject = this;
 editProject.title = 'Modal 1'; // This title should change based on which button is clicked
 editProject.save = function () {
 editProject.project.type = {type: 'Basic'}; //This item should change based on which button is clicked.

 $modalInstance.close(editProject.selected);

 Projects.$add(editProject.project).then(function(data) {editProject.projects.$save({ type: 'Basic' }); //'Basic' should change based on which button is clicked.   
   });
 };
 editProject.cancel = function () {
 $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
   };
 });
```

Javascript for Modal:

```
.state('selection.new', {
  url: '/new',
  onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', function ($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
            $modal.open({
   templateUrl: 'views/new-mark.html',
   controller: 'NewProjectCtrl as editProject',
})
    .result.finally(function () {
     $state.go('^');
    });
  }]
 })
```

HTML:

```
 <!-- HTML for button that triggers modal 1 -->

 <a ui-sref="selection.new">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="open()">Select</button>
 </a>

 <!-- HTML for modal title -->

 <div class="modal-header">
   <h3 class="modal-title">{{editProjects.type}}</h3>
 </div>
```

Comment: The controller you posted looks like the controller for the modal dialog (it's injecting $modalInstance), can you post the code where you call $modal.open? You can use the resolve option in the open function to define additional objects that are injected into the modal instance controller.

Comment: @Brad Barber I added the modal code. Sorry, I should've included that the first time around.

Answer (score 0):

You can define options to pass into the modal instance like this:

JS to open modal:

```
$modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'views/new-mark.html',
  controller: 'NewProjectCtrl as editProject',
  resolve: {
    dialogOptions: function() {
      return {
        title: $stateParams.type === 'Basic' ? 'Basic Title' : 'Advanced Title',
        type: $stateParams.type
      };
    }
  }
})
```

Then inject and use dialogOptions in your modal instance controller:

```
myApp.controller('NewProjectCtrl', function ($scope, $location,  $stateParams, Projects, $modalInstance, dialogOptions) {
 var editProject = this;
 editProject.title = dialogOptions.title;
 editProject.save = function () {
 editProject.project.type = dialogOptions.type;
```

The tricky part is that you're using onEnter for your state to open the dialog. The ng-click="open()" isn't doing anything right? So, maybe add a state parameter to represent the type - you could specify the ui-sref as follows (would need to update the state definition as well):

```
<a ui-sref="selection.new({type: 'Basic'})">
<a ui-sref="selection.new({type: 'Advanced'})">
```

State definition change if you set the type as a param in the state:

```
url: '/new?type',
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solution. I'm a little confused about what i should be entering in the `title` and `type` fields within the dialogOptions.

Comment: Can you confirm that ng-click="open()" is not doing anyting? If you remove it, your app still works the same right? I'll update the code above to show how you could set it from the state params.

Comment: From what I can tell, ng-click="open()" is superfluous. The modal still seems to work when I remove it.

Comment: I think with how you have it set up, you'd want to set dialogOptions from the state params (updated above).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. Would this still work if I wanted to use several buttons instead of just two? E.g., Basic, Advanced, Expert, etc.

Comment: Probably just write a function that accepts the type and returns the appropriate dialog options instead of having that logic inline.

Comment: That's the part that I'm struggling with. I'm trying to figure out a way to apply this to three or more buttons, where each button triggers a new title to the modal and additional key/values upon submission.